# symfony2: define several php constants in bundle

Tags: symfony

I need defined several PHP constants and i need use this constants in my bundle (controller, custom classes, entities..) Where best place to add this constants, that would be convenient for them to get?

Comment: Maybe defining them as Global variables; or maybe you need to create a custom class within similar namespace of other classes and make a new instance wherever might be used; or maybe you can define them in `config.yml` then use them

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not just create a class to store your constants and use the `use` statement to autoload it where needed?

**Define your constants...**

```
namespace My\CoolBundle\Constants;

class ConstantlyCool {
    const DEFAULT_COOLNESS_LEVEL = "newbie";
    const MAX_COOLNESS_LEVEL = "phpisuber01";
}
```

**Now use them...**

```
namespace My\CoolBundle\Controller;

use My\CoolBundle\Constants\ConstantlyCool;

class CoolController extends Controller {
    public function awesomeAction() {
        // Do cool stuff
        $cool_level = ConstantlyCool::DEFAULT_COOLNESS_LEVEL;

        return new Response(/* blah blah */);
    }
}
```

Comment: I also use this approach - it's by far the cleanest and easiest to work with for new devs on the team. I used to work on a project where the same constants were defined in different bundles and controllers, which in the end messed the logic big time and was a total mess.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution for my is setting these constants in Bundle Class, like that:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
    const SITE_NAME = 'Watchdev AR';
}
```

And use twig functions constant http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/constant.html invoke them

In whatever twig file:

```
{{ constant('AppBundle\\AppBundle::SITE_NAME') }}
```

I think this solution follow the best practices that Symfony (without entity in this case) http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

class sample
{const TEST_NUM= 10;}